# ASP.NET masterpages: how to insert markup in the head section inside the aspx?

Tags: asp.net, header, master-pages, declarative

I know I can [access the head section of a page which uses a masterpage programmatically](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/03/24/Access-to-a-page_2700_s-head-element-using-ASP.NET-2.0.aspx) this way (in code behind):

This is *only an example* (I'd like to insert scripts and styles etc.):

```
this.Header.Title = "I just set the page's title";
```

Is there a simple way to do this in a **declarative** way on **in the aspx file itself**?

Sometimes it would be handy to insert a **client script** or a **style declaration** or a link to an external resource.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this by using content regions in the `head`, in exactly the same way as you would in the `body` of the page. eg, In your masterpage:

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/common1.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/common1.js"></script>
    <asp:contentplaceholder id="ExtraStylesAndScripts" runat="server" />
</head>
```

And then in the page itself just something like:

```
<asp:content contentplaceholderid="ExtraStylesAndScripts" runat="server">    
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/extra1.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/extra2.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/extra1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/extra2.js"></script>
</asp:content>
```

Comment: D'oh! I'm such an idiot. I don't know, but I had this idea, that ContentPlaceholders could not be used in the head section... thanks a lot!

Comment: In VS2008 under 3.5 Visual Studio even does this for you when you create a MasterPage

Answer (score 6):

For **stylesheet** you can use this :

```
HtmlLink cssRef = new HtmlLink();
cssRef.Href = "addins/main.css";
cssRef.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
cssRef.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(cssRef);
```

For **Meta Tags** :

```
HtmlMeta metaTag = new HtmlMeta();
metaTag.Name = "author";
metaTag.Content = "ScarletGarden";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(metaTag);
```

But there is no way to add external script files to header element.

You can add inside body element by :

```
if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("myExternalScript"))
{
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("myExternalScript", "js/myJSFile.js");
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm looking for a solution doing it in a DECLARATIVE way.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the page title in the content page declaration.

```
<%@ Title="Page Title" Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Subpage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Subpage" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe my example is misleading. I'd like to insert other things, like ad-hoc styles for that individual page and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this.
But you can put HEAD element inside html with the enclosed string in asp style markup.

e.g.
`<%=myTitle%>`

Comment: I'm not interested in the title (it was only an example). I want to insert scripts, styles etc. using intellisense. I don't want to do it programmatically.